# How do I configure fuse-hdfs with autofs?

Tags: fuse, autofs

I am trying to setup autofs so it will automatically mount hdfs. From /etc/fstab if I have:

```
/fs1/fuse_dfs.wrapper.sh#dfs://namenode:9000   /hdfs fuse
```

this works.

Now I am trying to setup /etc/auto.master with this:

```
hdfs -fstype=fuse,rw,nodev,nonempty,noatime,allow_other :/fs1/fuse_dfs.wrapper.sh#dfs://namenode:9000 -debug
```

When I restart autofs I get:

```
handle_mounts: mount of /fs1/fuse_dfs.wrapper.sh#dfs://namenode:9000 failed!
```

References:

- http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/MountableHDFS/
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-4?focusedCommentId=12570484&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-12570484